# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>' when testing mocked http client with Mocktail

Tags: flutter, dart, mocking

I have written a test for a simple HTTP get using Mocktail to mock the HTTP client. When I call the get method in the test I receive "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future'".

Anyone any idea why this might be?

Here is the test:

```
class MockHttpClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  late IdRemoteDataSourceImpl dataSource;
  late MockHttpClient mockHttpClient;

  setUp(
    () {
      mockHttpClient = MockHttpClient();
      dataSource = IdRemoteDataSourceImpl(client: mockHttpClient);
    },
  );

  group('Get id', () {
    test(
      'when response code is 200',
      () async {
        final url = Uri.parse('https://api.test.com/');
        const tUsername = 'username';
        final accountJson = json.decode(
          fixture('account.json'),
          // ignore: avoid_as
        ) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final tIdModel = IdModel.fromJson(accountJson);
        // arrange
        when(() => mockHttpClient.get(url))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response(
                  fixture('account.json'),
                  200,
                ));
        // act
        final testResult = await dataSource.getId(tUsername);
        // assert
        // expect(testResult, tIdModel);
      },
    );
  });
}
```

The error occurs when the following line runs:

```
final testResult = await dataSource.getId(tUsername);
```

Code being tested:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class IdModel {
  IdModel({required this.id});

  final String id;

  factory IdModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return IdModel(id: json['id'].toString());
  }
}

abstract class IdRemoteDataSource {
  Future<IdModel> getId(String username);
}

class IdRemoteDataSourceImpl implements IdRemoteDataSource {
  IdRemoteDataSourceImpl({required this.client});

  final http.Client client;

  @override
  Future<IdModel> getId(String username) async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://api.test.com/query?username=$username');
    final response = await client.get(url);
    // ignore: avoid_as
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return IdModel.fromJson(responseJson);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Error `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future'...` occurs when you call method that has not been implemented for mock object or there are different parameters passed to it.

In your code you passed different url parameter to `get(...)` method. Http client mock waiting for `'https://api.test.com/'` but actually `'https://api.test.com/query?username=$username'` has been passed.

You have two options to solve it.

1. Pass the same url to mocked method from `when(...)` that will be passed during test:

```dart
const tUsername = 'username';
final url = Uri.parse('https://api.test.com/query?username=$tUsername');
...
// arrange
when(() => mockHttpClient.get(url))
  .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response(
      fixture('account.json'),
      200,
  ),
);
```

2. Use `any` matcher (if you don't care which parameter passed):

```dart
registerFallbackValue(Uri.parse(''));
...
when(() => mockHttpClient.get(any()))
  .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response(
      fixture('account.json'),
      200,
  ),
);
```

Comment: that's super, you fixed my problem and described why it was failing - very, very helpful :-)

I did find I need to add the following to the test setup before using any():

registerFallbackValue(Uri.parse('https://fake.url.com/'));

Comment: Good! Oh yes, you are right, type Uri needs to registerFallbackValue. Updaged my answer

Comment: I have the same issue, but I seem to be mocking correctly, since all my tests pass ok.  I posted my issue here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669624/

Comment: I'm using Mocktail to test flutter development, and in the official documentation, I didn't find this critical piece of information "or there are different parameters passed to it". Thank you