# Unit tests with mocktail pass but 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<>' runtime exception is thrown

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, null, mocking

There are similar issues asking about the same error (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899067)), but their cause was due to improper mocking.  In my case, I seem to have the method properly mocked, yet when I debug in Visual Studio Code with `All Exceptions` enabled, then I get the runtime exception:

```
_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<AuthenticationToken?>')
```

If I continue the test past the exception (or simply debug the tests with `All Exceptions` disabled or simply run them without debugging), all my tests pass ok.

```
dependencies:
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  mocktail: ^0.1.4
```

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class AuthenticationRepository {
  static const _currentTokenKey = 'key';
  AuthenticationToken? _inMemoryToken;
  Future<Box<AuthenticationToken?>> _tokenBox;
  ...
  Future<AuthenticationToken?> activeToken() async =>
      _inMemoryToken ?? (await _tokenBox).get(_currentTokenKey);
  ...
}
```

Sample test file:

```
import 'package:app/src/data/authentication/repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class MockAuthenticationRepository extends Mock
    implements AuthenticationRepository {}

void main() {
  AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository;
  SUT sut; // SUT depends on AuthenticationRepository

  setUp(() {
    authenticationRepository = MockAuthenticationRepository();

    when(() => authenticationRepository.activeToken())
      .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Future.value(AuthenticationToken()));
    
    sut = SUT(authenticationRepository);
  });

  test('some test', () async {
    await sut.someMethod();
    verify(() => authenticationRepository.activeToken()).called(1);
  });
}
```

[image: mocktail exception]

Here is the stack trace:

```
MockAuthenticationRepository.activeToken (/Users/davilin/Documents/Projects/app/flutter/app/lib/src/data/authentication/repository.dart:296)
main.initMocks.<anonymous closure> (/Users/davilin/Documents/Projects/app/flutter/app/test/network/token_refresh_interceptor_test.dart:33)
when.<anonymous closure> (/Users/davilin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mocktail-0.1.4/lib/src/mocktail.dart:211)
main.initMocks (/Users/davilin/Documents/Projects/app/flutter/app/test/network/token_refresh_interceptor_test.dart:33)
main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (/Users/davilin/Documents/Projects/app/flutter/app/test/network/token_refresh_interceptor_test.dart:52)
Declarer._runSetUps.<anonymous closure> (/Users/davilin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/test_api-0.4.2/lib/src/backend/declarer.dart:329)
Future.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:495)
Future.doWhile.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:535)
StackZoneSpecification._registerUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (/Users/davilin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stack_trace-1.10.0/lib/src/stack_zone_specification.dart:126)
StackZoneSpecification._run (/Users/davilin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stack_trace-1.10.0/lib/src/stack_zone_specification.dart:208)
StackZoneSpecification._registerUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (/Users/davilin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stack_trace-1.10.0/lib/src/stack_zone_specification.dart:126)
_rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436)
_CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335)
_CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244)
_CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1281)
Future.doWhile (dart:async/future.dart:551)
Future.forEach (dart:async/future.dart:493)
Declarer._runSetUps (/Users/davilin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/test_api-0.4.2/lib/src/backend/declarer.dart:329)
<asynchronous gap> (Unknown Source:0)
StackZoneSpecification._registerUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (/Users/davilin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stack_trace-1.10.0/lib/src/stack_zone_specification.dart:0)
<asynchronous gap> (Unknown Source:0)
```

I just wanted to document this, in case someone can offer an explanation why this happens.

Comment: can u share this function?  .get(_currentTokenKey)?

Comment: @pedropimont yes, it is from hive (2.0.4), box.dart.  source code is here:  https://github.com/hivedb/hive/blob/master/hive/lib/src/box/box.dart

Comment: You made AuthenticationToken is nullable, so your code can handle a null value from the future. The problem is not here. The problem is you are not getting a Future, you are getting null. I am not sure what causes the problem but it may be related to _inMemoryToken 's type. If _inMemoryToken is not a future, the compiler may get confused.

Comment: @EmreSURK thanks for the suggestion. To test I made activeToken() to return either a constant non-null value or a Future, but the error still occurs for all of them: (Sorry, comment format difficult to read): 1) Future<AuthenticationToken?> activeToken() => Future<AuthenticationToken?>(() => const AuthenticationToken()); 2) Future<AuthenticationToken?> activeToken() async => const AuthenticationToken(); 3) Future<AuthenticationToken?> activeToken() => _activeToken(); Future<AuthenticationToken?> _activeToken() async => _inMemoryToken ?? (await _tokenBox).get(_currentTokenKey);

Comment: How about that: Future<AuthenticationToken?>?

Comment: @EmreSURK yes, changing it to Future<AuthenticationToken?>? does work and there is no longer a runtime exception.

Comment: Cool, Does that resolve your problem? I think at least you can see the problem much more clear.

Comment: @EmreSURK thanks, it does resolve the runtime error itself, but not really an ideal solution, since it seems the problem is that something about mocktail expects an optional Future where the actual return type is non-optional.  But if you'd like to write up your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it as the solution as thanks for your troubleshooting assistance.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I followed up with the author of mocktail [here](https://github.com/felangel/mocktail/issues/88), and this is his explanation:

> This is working as expected. The issue is you have "All Exceptions" enabled instead of just "Uncaught Exceptions". Internally, mocktail handles catching the TypeErrors so you should just uncheck "All Exceptions" and you're good to go.
>
> Hope that helps